# Background not changing in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, background

I have some radio buttons on my webpage which are supposed to change the background on a div that's placed next to them, it's done correctly in FF, chrome, opera and safari, but not in IE.

The code:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylecopia.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#uno").click(function() {$("#cambiar").css("background-image","url(../wp-content/uploads/blanco2patas.jpg)")});
        $("#dos").click(function() {$("#cambiar").css("background-image","url(../wp-content/uploads/blanco4patas.jpg)")});
        $("#tres").click(function() {$("#cambiar").css("background-image","url(../wp-content/uploads/negro2patas.jpg)")});
        $("#cuatro").click(function() {$("#cambiar").css("background-image","url(../wp-content/uploads/negro4patas.jpg)")});
    });
</script>
<script>
    function comprobar() {
        inputs=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (x=0;x<inputs.length;x++) {
            if (inputs[x].value==""||inputs[x].value==" ") {
                alert('Hay un campo vacío, termine el formulario');
                return (false);
             }
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
<!--PAGE CONTENTS !-->
<div id="cambiar"></div>
<form action="p.php" onSubmit="return comprobar()" name="formulario" method="POST">
<label class="label_radio" for="sample-radio1">
<input name="opcion" required id="uno" checked="checked" value="White U" type="radio"/><span>&nbsp;Blanco U&nbsp;</span><br /><br/>
</label>
<label class="label_radio" for="sample-radio2">
<input name="opcion" id="dos" value="White Truss"  type="radio"/><span>&nbsp;Blanco Truss&nbsp;</span><br/><br/>
</label>
<label class="label_radio" for="sample-radio3">
<input name="opcion" id="tres" value="Black U"  type="radio"/><span>&nbsp;Negro U&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><br /><br/>
</label>
<label class="label_radio" for="sample-radio4">
<input name="opcion" id="cuatro" value="Black Truss" type="radio"/><span>&nbsp;Negro Truss&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><br/><br/>
</label>
<br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Internet Explorer, Format of the properties must be same, even spaces.Try using 'Background' property.

```
background:transparent url(../wp-content/uploads/blanco2patas.jpg);
```

`For Jquery:

```
$(this).css( "background", "url(../wp-content/uploads/negro4patas.jpg)" );
```

IE 7+ must work.

Comment: it works, thought my background shows too big now, not that that's related to the question, thanks!